# Unity Raycast2D ignored instantiated Prefab object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently making a small game for a university assignment. It's a simple 2D game where you shoot birds using the mouse.

I did collission detection by hand at first (check for x/y boundaries) but now I wanna use a collider.

So I added a **CircleCollider2D** to my objects and I perform the Raycast like so

```
Vector3 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);

RaycastHit2D[] hits = Physics2D.RaycastAll (mousePosition, Vector3.forward, Mathf.Infinity);
        Debug.Log (hits.Length);
```

Now when I add my prefabs manually into my scene it works as expected. The log outputs 1, or even 2 if I have multiple birds on top of each other.

But my game instantiated a lot of birds randomly and they are not detected when performing the raycast. I already checked, they definitely have colliders.

The instantiation code looks like the following:

```
Bird bird = Instantiate (birdPrefab, birdPosition, Quaternion.identity) as Bird;
```

I googled around for 2 hours now, but nothing could actually solve my problem.

I don't know if this is important, but the collision detection does not happen within the bird object's attached script.

I'm really cofused because it works with manually put objects, but not with instantiated ones. Has anybody experienced this before?

Edit:

The mouse position is on **(x, y, -10)** and the birds are on **(x, y, 0)** and both the manually placed ones and the instantiated ones are direct children of the scene.

Edit2:

Bird start

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    this.animator = this.GetComponent<Animator> ();

    this.camera = Camera.main;

    this.rigidBody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    // get the ammunition script
    this.ammunition = GameObject.Find ("Ammunition").GetComponent<Ammunition> ();
    // get the score script
    this.score      = GameObject.Find("Score").GetComponent<Score>();
}
```

Manually Placed Bird
[image: Manually placed bird]

Instantiated Bird
[image: Instatiated Bird]

Both have the collider and both are on the same Z level for the RayCast.

Comment: Can't tell anything wrong. Can you resize the birds and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

There do not seem to be any issues with your raycast or instantiation of the Bird, given the information you have provided. This leads me to believe there is a problem elsewhere in the code or in the way the scene is set up, especially if the non-instantiated bird works as expected.

If you can post a screenshot of both the manually placed Bird and instantiated Bird Gameobject information *during gameplay*, as well as any code performed on "bird" after instantiation, we can take a closer look.

Comment: Thanks. I added two screenshots and the startup code

Comment: This did actually work for a moment. But it seems to work and not work randomly, if I move randomly move around code., I kinda add and remove non related stuff , such as Debug.Log and suddenly it's not working anymore. I so don't get it. Started writing my own collusion detection, but then why use an engine after all.

Comment: Everything still appears to be ok. Is anything put into the log when you click on the birds?
As an FYI, Vector3.forward is probably not being used as you intend it to. Physics2D.Raycast is only looking for rays in the x and y direction, whereas Vector3.forward is shorthand for (0,0,1). Vector2.zero is what you would want here instead.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what part is "not working" with relevant code?

Comment: By not working I mean, that I click on a 2DBoxCollider and it doesn't detect a hit. As said, with Vector2.zero it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, depending whether I have Debug.Log somewhere or not. At least that is how it feels.